# CNTK: train Embedding layer initialized with pretrained embeddings?

Tags: cntk

The documentation of the `Embedding` layer (https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/layerref.html#embedding) shows that it can be initialized with pretrained embeddings using the `weights` parameter, but these embeddings are not updated during training.

Is there a way to initialize the `Embedding` layer with pretrained embeddings and still update them during training?

If not, what's the most efficient way to do batch embeddings look up with one hot vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just pass the initial values the `init` argument instead. That will create a learnable parameter initialized with the array you pass in.